# SSL certificate error in IE and chrome in apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

You attempted to reach www.domainname.domain.ac.in, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.domain.ac.in.
but the site works fine with https://domainname.domain.ac.in in all the browsers
This error showed up only in chrome and IE
when trying to access https://www.domainame.domain.ac.in

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Its a go daddy certificate.

Answer (score 3):

Wildcard certificates only works with a single level of domain name.

So if you have a cert for *.domain.ac.in it will work for 111.domain.ac.in, 222.domain.ac.in but not for 111.111.domain.ac.in.

More details are available on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)